# click coordinates, axes and imshow

Tags: matlab, user-interface, coordinates

I'm having some problems with MATLAB GUIDE.

I have an axes object in a GUI (axes1) which is displaying an image ( imshow(I) ). 
I need to store the coordinates of a user click on the image.

I tried

```
[x,y] = ginput(1).
```

The problem with this function is that it returns the coordinates of the axes, not the coordinates of the image I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of the axes and the image are aligned:

For example:

```
figure();
imshow('peppers.png');
[x,y]=ginput(1)
```

If you're bothered about out of bounds conditions, you could check and remove them after calling `ginput`:

```
if x> size(im,2)
   x = size(im,2);
end
if y> size(im,1)
   y = size(im,1);
end
```

Comment: no, they aren't. If I click on the corner of the object axes1, I get (x,y) > size(I)

Comment: @user1384636 do you mean that you get out of bounds results? You can check it and select the closest available point on the image.

Comment: So why don't set the axes limits according to the image?

Comment: @Adiel, I am not sure that I understand you.

Comment: I'll try in other words- You define the limits and coordinates of  `axes1` in the GUI. Why not define it exactly in the size of the image? than the coordinate from `ginput` will be equal to the coordinates on the picture.

Comment: @user1384636, When you say "_I get (x,y) > size(I)_", can you give the actual numbers for `x`, `y` and `size(I)` ? Also you should include these details into your original post to make the question more defined.

Comment: @Adiel, the coordinates from `ginput` equal to the coordinates on the image, unless you are selecting a point that is out of image bounds.

Comment: @Andrey Sorry, i didn't notice that you asked the question, not user1384636. My comment was to him.